# storing data from a file and passing it to a new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

code below is used to get a string from a edittext and stores it in a file, this only works for 1 edittext, if i used two edittext it doesnt work, also i would like to show the results on another activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     File myInternalFile;
     File myExternalFile;
    private String filename = "MySampleFile.txt";
    private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void saveInternalHandler(View view) 
 {
    EditText myInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myInputText);
    TextView responseText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseText);
    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new 
    ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    myInternalFile = new File(directory , filename);

try {

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myInternalFile);
    fos.write(myInputText.getText().toString().getBytes());
    fos.close();
 } 

catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
    myInputText.setText("");
    responseText.setText("MySampleFile.txt saved to Internal Storage...");
 }

public void getInternalHandler(View view) 
 {
    EditText myInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myInputText);
    TextView responseText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseText);
    String myData = "";

try {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myInternalFile);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    myData = myData + strLine;
 }
    in.close();
 } 
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();
 }
    myInputText.setText(myData);
    responseText.setText("MySampleFile.txt data retrieved from Internal Storage...");
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're writing the `String` to a file instead of sending it to another activity using an `Intent` or `SharedPreference`?

Comment: here is the best Example : http://javatechig.com/android/pass-a-data-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android

Answer (score 0):

A little more detail about how this doesn't work with two EditTexts would be nice. But my guess is that you are finding that only the text from the second is displayed, this is because when you call

`myInternalFile = new File(directory , filename);`

for the second time you are creating a  *new*  file in `directory` with same name as the old one, i.e. you are overwriting the old one. You need `myInternalFile` to be a global variable.

As for how to pass data, especially strings, between activities this is a good resource:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/

Comment: Ok, I've end up using two buttons, one to save the name of a person, and another to save the weight in two separate files. Now i want to view these on the main activity. How do i display files into a textview? Sorry i'm a novice.